# Quicker activation for Ring of Invisibility

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, action-economy

Is there any way to increase the activation speed of a ring of invisibility to be anything but a standard action?

If not, is there anything that can apply a short burst of invisibility as a move or swift action?

The goal of this is getting a slayer reliably employ the advanced talent assassination more often.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for feats or class features, but [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67755/8610) may also be of interest.

Comment: While that is helpful, I plan on using it as a character with a slayer's assassinate talent, and dropping it from a standard means i can practically assassinate every other turn. That is instead of having 2 turn downtime between them. So aiming for within the bounds of existing items before trying to argue for a magic item. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome to keep this question as-is, but you might want to ask that question also; i.e. *How can a slayer reliably employ the advanced talent assassination more often?*

Comment: I would just add the context to the end of it.

Comment: I also had a question that was similar and there might be info thats helpful https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83963/23058 as one of the answers breaks down that the boots of speed had an additional quirk

Comment: I'm late for battle, sorry. Just read this one, and since we had a munchkin/cheater that made us research the topic, I figured I might offer some of the things we found. Have a happy game.

Answer (score 2):

First answering the main part, cause it popped up in one of my games:

**Q: Is there any way to increase the activation speed of a ring of invisibility to be anything but a standard action?

A: No**

The reason here is the action economy balance. Assuming you can use your ring of invisibility with anything else than a standard action, you could use the standard to attack, then become invisible on the same round. Functionally, your Ring of Invisibility just becames a discount Ring of Greater Invisibility.

As a rule of thumb, activated magic items replicate something using a standard action. Allowing them to be used with anything less would allow people to, for instance, cast two (or more) spells per round, which is most of the time impossible<sup>1</sup>.

Supporting that, there are some items allowing you to quicken your casting<sup>2</sup>, but they only work a few times per day and are rather expensive.  Moreover, they do not apply to activating magic items.

To any sane DM out there, asked if your player can quick/mmediate action activate their magic items that do not explicitly state it: bad idea.  But hey, if you manage to immediately activate items, let me know, I have a wand of *Fireball* somewhere that became a lot more interesting.

#### Second question

**Q: If not, is there anything that can apply a short burst of invisibility as a move or swift action?

A: I can't tell you with certainty there is not.**

Some class features may cosmetically do that, but to the best extent of my knowledge, there is not. Cool spell such as *Blink* clearly state that even while being invisible 50% of the time, your opponents do not lose their DEX bonus to AC. The probability there is a way to do so is slim, cause the game designers have been extremely cautious about Sneak-attack like feature.<sup>3</sup>
However, you have more ways than Invisibility to trigger your roguish/slayerish features, and just asking a general way to do so, as Hey I Can Chan suggested might yield more results.

<sub>1: Except a few cases explicitly stated in the rules. Such exceptions including but not  limiting to: Quickened Spell, immediate action spell such as *Feather Fall*, some Magus features if I recall.

2: Namely *Metamagic Rods of Quicken Lesser/Greater*.

3: Or, as some say on the forums: Rogues can't have nice things. I am personnaly of the opinion that there is a cabale of game designers bent on curbing my fun of one shotting encounters, but my friends say I'm raving. So, up to you to make your own opinion.</sub>

Comment: digressions on game design doesn't answer this question, -1.  Also factually incorrect, see the Ninja base class as a single example of many.

Comment: @user2754 You're right I forgot the Vanishing trick of the Ninja when I answered. A list of the many options would make for a good answer to the second part of the question.